# ナビゲーションバーのレビューアイコンに赤い丸が表示されているのはなぜ？

Tags: サポート, デザイン, レビュー

権限「[レビュー キューへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)」により、ナビゲーションバーのユーザー名の隣にレビュー キュー用のリンクが表示されます。これはドロップダウンリストになっており、クリックすることで「各項目にレビューされていないキューが入っているかどうか」を確認することが出来ます。

あるとき、このレビュー キューのアイコンの右上に赤い丸が表示されていました。そしてドロップダウンリストをクリックすると、通常レビュー キューが存在すると**灰色の丸が表示される場所に赤色の丸が表示**されていました。

この赤い丸は何ですか？また、これはどのような条件で表示されますか？

[image: ドロップダウンリストに赤い丸が表示されており、そのリストを開くと「編集の提案」という項目に赤色の丸が、「クローズ票」という項目には灰色の丸が表示されている]

---

### 関連投稿

- [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226)
- [What criteria should we use to determine which review queue indicator a site will have? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305893)
- [Red Indicator Light Falsely Positive Most of the Time - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338688)
- [What does the red circle mean next to a review queue? - Physics Meta Stack Exchange](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10381)

Answer (score 4):

[関連投稿に挙げられたリンク先](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226) を読む限り、ドット (=通知の目印) が付くのはキューがある場合で

- 灰色 = 1個から閾値以下
- 赤色 = 閾値以上

なお、閾値はレビューキューの種類によってそれぞれ異なる…と書いてあるようです。

ただし今現在「編集の提案」に赤ドットが付くにも関わらず、開いたところで何も表示されません。
正しく動作していないのか、削除された投稿に対して編集キューが残ったままになっている？